# Socket.io number of rooms, the client is in is growing after each reconnect

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I have a simple socket.io server (**1.1.0** vesrion) where users can join/leave rooms. The problem is that when the user disconnects (reload the page) he is not leaving the room he is in.

When I print the list of rooms he is in, it is always growing.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(client){
  client.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log(client.adapter.rooms);
  } 
}
```

The first time user disconnects I see:

```
{ V_6ilicTsMPK9CGQAAAA: []}
```

After a few times of reloading the page, on the disconnect I see:

```
{ V_6ilicTsMPK9CGQAAAA: [],
  '6g1CpUyyKQtAbI4AAAAB': [],
  MS1VY1yxtVyRaG3XAAAC: [],
  TtXxNqVu5sHq0e9CAAAD: [],
  ...
  '1bPs4CRLQhEH0NKIAAAJ':
```

I tried to manually leave rooms by doing client.leaveAll(); and even iterating through `client.adapter.rooms` and removing by `client.leave(room)` but the situation is the same.

What can I do with this infinitely growing list of rooms.

Answer (score 0):

Your `client.adapter.rooms` lists all rooms. And as you can see the rooms are still there but they are empty. It is interesting to see that every client has also its own room.

Before disconnect it looks like this:

```
'SomeRoom': [ ihN6vFupWqXHsKgKAAAF: true ]
ihN6vFupWqXHsKgKAAAF: [ ihN6vFupWqXHsKgKAAAF: true ]
```

Aftere disconnect:

```
'SomeRoom': []
ihN6vFupWqXHsKgKAAAF: []
```

I don't know if socket.io removes empty rooms at some point.